# Data Fetching Problem , Faster Data Fetching tool

Tags: sql-server, database

In my Query I use Indexing, but data fetch the result in 5 mint, or sometimes 7 mint.
I have 4284399770 records in one table.
is any tool that fetches data faster using an SQL server?
Kindly recommend any tool or service which fetches data fastly.

```
  Declare @FromDate Datetime  ='2019-06-27 16:57:01.000'        
Declare @Todate Datetime =    '2019-06-28 16:29:19.000'        
Declare @register_ID int =-9999    
Declare @location_number int =-9999    
Declare @receipt_number int =-9999    
Declare @VenueID int =-9999  
Declare @MediaType int =-9999
select        
 EJTable.register_ID'Terminal ID'        
,EJTable.location_number         
,EJTable.receipt_number        
,EJTable.VenueID'clerk NO'        
,EJTable.Sale_Total        
,EJTable.Receipt_date_time        
,EJTable.SQLPostDate        
from  EJTable WITH (NOLOCK,INDEX( IX_Receipt_Date_Time))  
INNER JOIN EJMediaTable WITH (NOLOCK ,INDEX (IX_MediaType) ) ON EJMediaTable.Transaction_Number = EJTable.Transaction_Number 
where          
(EJTable.Receipt_date_time between @FromDate and @Todate)      
and    
(isnull (@register_ID ,-9999)=-9999 or  EJTable.register_ID=@register_ID)    
and     
(isnull (@location_number , -9999)=-9999 or  EJTable.location_number=@location_number)    
and    
(isnull (@receipt_number ,-9999)=-9999 or  EJTable.receipt_number=@receipt_number)    
and    
(isnull (@VenueID ,-9999)=-9999 or  EJTable.VenueID=@VenueID) 
and
(isnull (@MediaType ,-9999)=-9999 or  EJMediaTable.MediaType=@MediaType)
```

Comment: What you have there is a "catch-all" or "kitchen-sink" query. These need a different method of writingto ensure that they are performant for different sets of parameters. Both Bertrand and Shaw did some great articles on these: [An Updated Kitchen Sink Example](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) and [Catch-all Queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)

Comment: Also, do you *really* need `NOLOCK`? Do you understand the implications of its use? Also, it's very rare you need to tell the RDBMS what index it needs to use too; I doubt telling it here will be helpful and in fact could well be detrimental.

Comment: @Larnu Yes sir i need Nolock .
Sir, I also do a query using sp_executesql but still face issue

Comment: Why do you "need" it? If you really "need" it, I would suggest it only needs to be against one, or you should be setting the isolation level at batch level; not against each table.

Comment: @Larnu sir any other option for data fetch?

Comment: Try adding the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` query hint and remove the index hint.

Answer (score 1):

I would, personally create a dynamic query here. You could use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, however, as you have a variety of different queries that could be run here (due the having 5 `NULL`able parameters), I feel that using a dynamic approach with only the clauses in the `WHERE` that are required gives the RDBMS the best chance.

As mentioned by both myself and Guzman, I've removed both the hints as well; these are more likely to do more harm than good for different reasons. `NOLOCK` as the query could return wrong results, and the `INDEX` hint as it's unlikely that index will be helpful for the 15 or so different queries that would be run.

I can't test this query, as there's no sample data, but you can use your best friend to debug any errors:

```sql
DECLARE @FromDate datetime = '2019-06-27T16:57:01.000',
        @Todate datetime = '2019-06-28T16:29:19.000',
        @register_ID int, --Use NULL, not a random non-NULL value
        @location_number int, --Use NULL, not a random non-NULL value
        @receipt_number int, --Use NULL, not a random non-NULL value
        @VenueID int, --Use NULL, not a random non-NULL value
        @MediaType int; --Use NULL, not a random non-NULL value

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT EJT.register_ID AS [Terminal ID],' + @CRLF +
           N'       EJT.location_number,' + @CRLF +
           N'       EJT.receipt_number,' + @CRLF +
           N'       EJT.VenueID AS [clerk NO],' + @CRLF +
           N'       EJT.Sale_Total,' + @CRLF +
           N'       EJT.Receipt_date_time,' + @CRLF +
           N'       EJT.SQLPostDate' + @CRLF +
           N'FROM dbo.EJTable EJT' + @CRLF +                                                                --Removed hints, they are very uinlikely to help here
           N'     JOIN dbo.EJMediaTable EJMT ON EJT.Transaction_Number = EJTM.Transaction_Number' + @CRLF + --And are actually more likely to cause worse performance
           N'WHERE EJT.Receipt_date_time >= @FromDate AND EJT.Receipt_date_time <= @ToDate' +
           CASE WHEN @register_ID IS NOT NULL THEN  @CRLF + N'  AND EJT.Register_ID = @Register_ID' ELSE '' END +
           CASE WHEN @location_number IS NOT NULL THEN  @CRLF + N'  AND EJT.location_number = @location_number' ELSE '' END +
           CASE WHEN @receipt_number IS NOT NULL THEN  @CRLF + N'  AND EJT.receipt_number = @receipt_number' ELSE '' END +
           CASE WHEN @VenueID IS NOT NULL THEN  @CRLF + N'  AND EJT.VenueID = @VenueID' ELSE '' END +
           CASE WHEN @MediaType IS NOT NULL THEN  @CRLF + N'  AND EJTM.MediaType = @MediaType' ELSE '' END + N';';


--PRINT @SQL; --Your best friend
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@FromDate datetime, @Todate datetime, @register_ID int, @location_number int, @receipt_number int, @VenueID int, @MediaType int',
                       @FromDate, @ToDate, @register_ID, @location_number, @receipt_number, @VenueID, @MediaType;
```